# SwiftUI: dismiss keyboard on button click for TextField in deep hierarchy

Tags: swiftui

I have a `TextField` somewhere deep in the hierarchy, and a `Button` that need to dismiss the `TextField`'s keyboard upon tapping, the example I found so far are:

1. Use `FocusState` and set it to dismiss keyboard in button's action
2. Use `UIApplication.shared.sendActio(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)` in button action

If I prefer method 1, do I have to pass a `focused` state variable all the way to the `TextField`, or is there a better approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass the focus state binding through all those intermediate views, an alternative would be to pass the focus information with `environment` (from parent to child) and `preference` (from child to parent).

This is quite a lot of boilerplate, and might be more effort than passing the focus state binding, depending on how deeply nested the text fields are.

Suppose we have some text fields that we want to control focus, that is nested in a view called `Nested`.

```
enum FocusedTextField {
    case one, two
}

struct Nested: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextFields()
    }
}

struct TextFields: View {
    @State var text1 = "Foo"
    @State var text2 = "Bar"
    @FocusState var focus: FocusedTextField?
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            TextField("One", text: $text1)
                .focused($focus, equals: .one)
            TextField("Two", text: $text2)
                .focused($focus, equals: .two)
        }
    }
}
```

We can now add a `FocusKey` that is both an environment key and a preference key:

```
struct FocusKey: EnvironmentKey, PreferenceKey {
    static func reduce(value: inout FocusedTextField?, nextValue: () -> FocusedTextField?) {
        // "??", because we only want to find the focused view across the sibling views
        value = nextValue() ?? value
    }
    
    static let defaultValue: FocusedTextField? = nil
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var focus: FocusedTextField? {
        get { self[FocusKey.self] }
        set { self[FocusKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Now in `TextFields`, we can add the `\.focus` environment, set `focus` when the environment changes, and also set the preference to `focus.`

```
@Environment(\.focus) var focusFromEnvironment

// ...

Group {
    ...
}
.onChange(of: focusFromEnvironment) { _, new in
    focus = new
}
.preference(key: FocusKey.self, value: focus)
```

Now, in the root view, we can have an unfocus button like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var focus: FocusedTextField? = nil
    var body: some View {
        Nested()
            .environment(\.focus, focus)
            .onPreferenceChange(FocusKey.self) { new in
                // when something is focused, this gets called
                focus = new
            }
        Button("Unfocus") {
            // setting this changes the environment
            focus = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **model** which both views have access to; they can read and update the value of the focus state.

Play with the code below and see if it helps.

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation

@Observable class Model {
    var isTextFieldFocused = false
}

struct Root: View {
    @State private var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        Parent()
            .environment(model)

        Child()
            .environment(model)
    }
}

struct Parent: View {
    @Environment(Model.self) private var model

    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle Focus") {
            model.isTextFieldFocused.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {
    @Environment(Model.self) private var model
    @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text Field", text: $text)
            .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
            .onChange(of: model.isTextFieldFocused, initial: true) {
                isTextFieldFocused = model.isTextFieldFocused
            }
    }
}
```